# Weekday of first day of month

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, date, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I need to get the weekday of the first day of the month. For example, for the  current month September 2013 the first day falls on Sunday.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to get the weekday for the 1st of each month? Sept 1, 2013 is Sunday, Oct 1 2013 is Tuesday, etc.

Comment: @rmaddy yes I mean that

Comment: @Wain I have tried to play with date components, weekday ordinal, weekdays etc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At first, get the first day of current month (for example):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:(NSEraCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];
components.day = 1;
NSDate *firstDayOfMonth = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
```

Then use NSDateFormatter to print it as a weekday:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"]; 
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:firstDayOfMonth]);
```

P.S. also take a look at [Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution to getting the weekday name of the first day in the current month

```
NSDateComponents *weekdayComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
weekdayComps = [calendar.currentCalendar components:calendar.unitFlags fromDate:calendar.today];
weekdayComps.day = 1;
NSDateFormatter *weekDayFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[weekDayFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSString *firstweekday = [weekDayFormatter stringFromDate:[calendar.currentCalendar dateFromComponents:weekdayComps]];
NSLog(@"FIRST WEEKDAY: %@", firstweekday);
```

For the weekday index, use this

```
NSDate *weekDate = [calendar.currentCalendar dateFromComponents:weekdayComps];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar.currentCalendar components: NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate: weekDate];
NSUInteger weekdayIndex = [components weekday];
NSLog(@"WEEKDAY INDEX %i", weekdayIndex);
```

You can also increment or decrement the month if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the output you need you may use `NSDateFormatter` (as it was already said) or you may use `NSDateComponents` class. `NSDateFormatter` will give you a string representation, `NSDateComponents` will give you integer values. Method `weekday` may do what you want.

```
NSDateComponents *components = ...;
NSInteger val = [components weekday];
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift 4.2**

First:

```
extension Calendar {
    func startOfMonth(_ date: Date) -> Date {
        return self.date(from: self.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: date))!
    }
}
```

Second:

```
self.firstWeekDay = calendar.component(.weekday, from: calendar.startOfMonth(Date()))
```