# How to determine the localized first day of month?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, nsdateformatter, nscalendar, nslocalizedstring

I have to find the *day* that the 1st of each month falls on to be able to create a custom calendar; for instance, September 1, 2015 falls on a Tuesday, which makes Tuesday the first day of the month.

I have this code which works for English language countries, but for other countries, it fails because it doesn't translate correctly.

```
    //  build date as start of month
monthDateComponents.year = components.year;
monthDateComponents.month = components.month;
monthDateComponents.day = 1;

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDate *builtDate =[gregorian dateFromComponents: monthDateComponents];

NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
[df setDateFormat:@"E"];    
NSString *firstDay = [df stringFromDate:builtDate];

//  now, convert firstDay to the numeric day number
if([firstDay isEqual:NSLocalizedString(@"Sun",nil)])
    return 7;
else if([firstDay isEqual:NSLocalizedString(@"Mon",nil)])
    return 1;
else if([firstDay isEqual:NSLocalizedString(@"Tue",nil)])
    return 2;
else if([firstDay isEqual:NSLocalizedString(@"Wed",nil)])
    return 3;
else if([firstDay isEqual:NSLocalizedString(@"Thu",nil)])
    return 4;
else if([firstDay isEqual:NSLocalizedString(@"Fri",nil)])
    return 5;
else if([firstDay isEqual:NSLocalizedString(@"Sat",nil)])
    return 6;
```

Is there a better way of doing this so I don't have to go through each country and find what the 3 character abbreviation for each day is?  (for instance, in French, the day abbreviation for Saturday returns "sam.".)  The way I have this coded now, I need to know each and every language that my app is localized for (10 of them) make it work correctly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This code, and your resulting problem, don't make sense. What result are you trying to get? If it's the localized string, you are already getting it from the `NSDateFormatter`. If it's the weekday number, then you shouldn't be involving the formatter at all: get that date component from the calendar after constructing the inital date.

Comment: Hi Josh... I don't see any date component which will give me the first day of the month; weekday component will just give me the day number of the date passed.  I need to get the day number of the first day of each month to build a calendar.  As I indicated, it works fine for English speaking countries, but not localized.

Comment: Once you construct the date, using the date components and the calendar, you can get any date component _for that date_ from the calendar. If you want the weekday component _of that date_, you can get it.

Comment: duplicate of [Weekday of first day of month](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18860241)

Comment: I got it working... Thanks again Josh... I appreciate it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, it uses a smart calendar calculation of NSCalendar.

```
  NSDateComponents *components = [NSDateComponents new];
  components.day = 1;
  NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

  NSDate *firstDayOfMonth = [gregorian nextDateAfterDate:builtDate matchingComponents:components options: NSCalendarMatchNextTime | NSCalendarSearchBackwards];
  NSInteger weekdayIndex = [gregorian component:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:firstDayOfMonth];
  NSLog(@"weekday number: %ld", weekdayIndex);
  return weekdayIndex;
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue of the localized abbreviation of the day, which then has to be converted to a day number.

Comment: I edited the post to return the weekday index, the localization doesn't matter in this case. As mentioned in another answer, in the gregorian calendar index 1 is Sunday

Comment: I modified what you showed using weekdayIndex, and it works... thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
return [gregorian component:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:builtDate];
```

This gives you an integer telling you the weekday for that date.  1 is Sunday.